# Помощь в определении ошибки

Tags: matlab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Суть такова, не умею программировать в MATLAB задали задание, не сталкивался до этого с написанием кодов, в чем ошибка?,  должен получится график, но ругается перед запуском [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где ошибка-то? На приведенном скриншоте видно только предупреждение с полезным (с точки зрения MATLAB'а советом)

Comment: Дело в том, что должен вылезти график, а эти предупреждения не дают этого сделать

Comment: И я не знаю что делать собственно говоря(добавил график, который должен появиться)

Comment: Почему Вы думаете, что дело в предупреждениях? Насколько я помню, в Матлабе графики рисуются функцией `plot()`. На скриншоте я ничего похожего на ее вызов не вижу.

Comment: Я делал по листингу из учебника, возможно в новой программе используется как раз-таки этот plot() я о нем не знал

Comment: А вы бы не могли подсказать куда мне этот plot() вставить надо, чтобы график появился?

Comment: Не знаю насчет новой, я последний раз пользовался Матлабом лет 15 назад, `plot()` тогда уже был. В любом случае, для создания графика надо вызвать какую-то соответствующую функцию (`plot` или не `plot` - не суть важно). У Вас же ничего похожего не видно.

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что на скриншоте представлена функция, поставляющая 2 переменные.
Чтобы построить по ним график можно либо:

1. В другом м-файле вызвать эту функцию, н-р:

   ```
   [x,t]=eiler(входные переменные)
   ```

   И собственно график

   ```
   plot(x,t)
   ```
2. Вызвать график прямо в функции (что не очень хорошо)

   ```
   plot(x,t)
   ```

Comment: Важно не забыть перед использованием функции сохранить её с соответствующим именем м-файла. В данном случае eiler.m В противном случае Матлаб не сможет её найти.